# Android app is not compatible on any devices after publishing

Tags: android, google-api, android-manifest, google-play-services

I have just published my app on google play and found out that none of my testing devices are compatible. Even in the developer consol there is the compatible devices section and under that it says there are 7041 devices and 0 are compatible with my app.

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="*********************"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="2" android:required="true" android:name="GLES2.0"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"          
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
     android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.*************************"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.*************************" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <!--  android:launchMode = "singleInstance">-->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.******************************" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Any ideas why this would be having this effect?

here are the permissions my app requires

full network access
view network connections

i am using google play services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working after speaking with google support

this line

```
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="2" android:required="true" android:name="GLES2.0"/>
```

should have been

```
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

i got the fist method from a tutorial but i cant for the life of me remember which one, so just becareful what resources you use because they are not always correct

Answer (score 3):

Because in manifest you have mentioned

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

which support from 14 to 18. Increase your targetsdk version to 21. min sdk version to 11
  ( android 3.0 to 4.4)

```
 <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="11" // you can target from android 3.0 as your wish
  android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try that right now, on side note when i update the apk in google play is it instant or the same as uploading from new (couple of hours wait)

Comment: okay..surely will work :) after updating new apk in playstore. happy coding :) @Rob85

Comment: i hope so :-) it was exciting times uploading my first app to find it didnt work haha fingers crossed

Comment: lol.no worries.cool will work :) congratz and all the best for your first release. :)

Comment: No it doesnt seem to have worked. My test devices also arnt compatible even though i created the app using them. on google play where it tells me why the devices arnt supported i get this Vodafone HTC HTC Desire C
No carrier Samsung GT-P3110

Comment: what's the version of those devices? @Rob85

Comment: HTC is 4.0.3 and GT is 4.2.2 i dont think it has anything to do with the devices, i am guessing that no devices can see my app in the store

Comment: you run that apk in those devices and tested? not worked? @Rob85

Comment: when you publish in playstore, check whether you choose low maturity level. don't use high maturity which restricts some device in settings. low maturity is universal to all.https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en @Rob85

Comment: it is currently set to 'everyone'

Comment: Just spoke with google support and the problem is something to do with the opengles2.0 part, i am just not sure what yet

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```